# Transparency settings for my drop down terminal is not loading at start up

Tags: gnome-terminal, display

I am currently using Manjaro (Juhraya 18.1.5) and I use [guake] [1] as a dropdown terminal. I have set a transparency on it and wanted to launch it as a start up program. But after logging in, I find no transparency of the background. Everything else works perfectly fine.
If I quit it and relaunch it, transparency works fine.

Here are some info that might be useful:

```
System:
  Host: XD Kernel: 5.4.17-1-MANJARO x86_64 bits: 64 Desktop: KDE Plasma 5.17.5 
  Distro: Manjaro Linux


Graphics:
      Device-1: Intel Skylake GT2 [HD Graphics 520] driver: i915 v: kernel 
      Display: x11 server: X.Org 1.20.7 driver: intel unloaded: modesetting 
      resolution: 1366x768~60Hz 
      OpenGL: renderer: Mesa DRI Intel HD Graphics 520 (Skylake GT2) v: 4.6 Mesa 19.3.3
```

I found one solution, to add a delay timer in the start-up script. But I was wondering if there was anything more I could do to solve this problem.
Also what is causing the problem here?
Thanks.
[1]: http://guake-project.org/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

About my system information... I am using Kubuntu with KDE plasma v:5.18.5.
Here is what I did.

1. I installed "gcc"  from the terminal window.The "gcc" is a program that translates the C language text code in machine code.
2. I have have created a text file, called "start-guake.c" and then I written the code in that text document(the extension must be ".c" not ".txt").
3. After that,in the terminal, I changed the directory to the location of the text file and I COMPILED it with "gcc" (in the command line write gcc followed by the path of the text file that contains the code: "gcc /path/to/file.c"). This action resulted in the creation of a file named "a.out" (you will find it in the same folder where you have your text file that contains  the code)and this is the actual program.
4. I renamed the file from "a.out" to "start-guake" and moved it in the "/bin/" directory.
5. From there I went to my applications menu and opend "autostart" and in there I added the newly created program.
6. I restarted the computer after all these steps.
   This is the code:

   ```
    #include <stdlib.h>
    #include <stdio.h> 
    #include <string.h>

    void waitTenSeconds();

    int main(){
        waitTenSeconds();
        system("guake");
        return 0;
    }

    void waitTenSeconds(){
        system("sleep 10");
    }
   ```

Hope this helped.
Good luck !

Comment: actually I did the same but with a shell script :)

Answer (score 2):

The reason for this in my opinion is that the startup task is being launched before the system is fully ready to make transparency options available for that window. Or some how it is loading the program so early that the config file for guake has not been read yet. Making it appear as if it is being launched by another user with no transparency options set.

Comment: I have had the exact same thing happen to Tilda, or at least it appears to be the same issue. Is there maybe some kind of hook for when startup finishes?

Answer (score 0):

I can confirm what Michael Prokopec is saying.
I have solved the problem by writing a small program in C, that starts the  terminal in 10 seconds after loading the desktop environment and i ran this at startup with Autorun.
For me, the problem was that I could not run a script at startup for some reason, so thats why I resorted to C.

Comment: Do you mind sharing your code or pseudo code so that others can benefit from this logic?

Comment: aaa...sorry I forgot about that :D.I will dot in about an hour or so, because now I have somethig to do.

Comment: Ok.. I am back.

Comment: Beat you to it. In my case this is an executable script in my path (and I'm starting Tilda, which has the same problem, if you can call it the terminal's fault.) 
`sleep 10`; `tilda` (sorry the formatting is weird.) Oh, and I put the script in my "session and startup" where it would have been. For what it's worth OP did say they didn't just want a delay.

Comment: Yes this is a great work around.